# Is there a way to change speed in Adobe Connect?

Tags: adobe, adobe-connect

I know Adobe Connect launches its separate application but is there a way to change the speed (ie 2x) in the application or some other way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can download the page contents including the voice file.

1- Open in the web browser. Then just append

```
/output/content.zip?download=zip
```

to the page URL and press enter.

2- Extract the downloaded file. The file with a similar name to 'voip.flv' is the voice file.

3- You can open it with vlc or any other player and make benefit of the speed option.

Example:

If the link is like:

```
https://connect.labla.la/p9lhdwnhnf89/?session=breez7b98svagh3mqtkqb&html-view=false&proto=true
```

you can download the content with this link:

```
https://connect.labla.la/p9lhdwnhnf89/output/content.zip?download=zip
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no option to change the playback speed of an Adobe Connect Recording. A workaround is to download mp4 version of the recording and serve via a video hosting provider which has video speed option.